# How to reverse find "b" in pow(a, b, c)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, cryptography, padding, pow

```
from Crypto.Util.number import *
from Crypto.Util.Padding import *

# TEXT is unkown

a = 2
b = bytes_to_long(pad(TEXT, 256))
c = getStrongPrime(1024) #178421928611071019360267030334948865864898765051649286940999740284901927205871904589008975999166343705176087678836390158248443701521112359395642244010241537603886223197773601996752130369527788156850561634811382810306708743274890833005691607859804295513120809249269263095276488896526807638635252842937565466271
y = pow(a, b, c) #21343660735918737508327032642093044458513430667350324146942601945958232402677794381334538380151928312459028941815432844601005666496537855378093591308495810737072737197378249689765750242912228630158636001591313536255003252774830039438050786246884290993531824792273255248565666477421036484450980164795516106937
```

How do you find TEXT?
It looks like some people have figured this out, but I can't seem to solve this.

I tried brute-forcing, but it takes so long and I can't figure out TEXT.

Comment: This is called the discrete log problem. For large primes `c` this is a very hard problem in general. This difficulty is why several of the most important public key cryptography schemes are based on it. There are of course scenarios in which poorly chosen primes or other flaws and mistakes can make the problem solvable.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on President's answer, it's not only a hard problem in general, but *the* hard problem that underlies a large portion of modern cryptography.

The discrete log problem can be expressed, given known values `g,p,g**x`, find `x`. The discrete log problem has been around for some time, and was proposed by Whitfield Diffie and Martin Hellman in 1976 as the basis for key-exchange.

Because the DH problem becomes tractable for an adversary with access to a quantum computer capable of running Schnorr's algorithm, there have been efforts for the last several years to formalize Post Quantum primitives not relying on the hardness of discrete logs.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_logarithm